# Avoid duplicate entries for the same field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-migrations

I have a model `choice` in django. which has foreign key relationship with `user` model and `items` model.
Each user can choose as many items as he wants from `items` model, the `choice` model will keep track of how many users have chosen what items.
a particular user could be able to choose an item only once, but my problem is that when user1 select any item no other user can choose that one again.

this is my code for choice fill.

**Views.py**

```
def choice_fill(request, cid):
    item_list = item.objects.all()
    title = "Choice Filling"
    page = "Choice Filling"
    if request.method == "POST":
        usr = user.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
        # return render(request, 'success.html',{'stud':stud})
        if usr.isactive != 1:
            messages.error(request, "Your registration process is incomplete.")
        else:
            if not choice.objects.filter(item_id_id=cid, isactive=1).exists():
                userid = usr.id
                c = choice(user_id_id=studid, item_id_id=cid, isactive=1)
                c.save()
            else:
                return HttpResponse('multiple Entry not allowed')
```

**models.py**

```
class user(models.Model):
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

class item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

class choice(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now())
    isactive = models.BooleanField()
```

Comment: You need to filter by the current user id when you check if the choice exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake that is item_id is not Foreign key instead it is ManyToManyField.
Here is the docs [Django Many to Many Relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

So change it to

```
item_id = models.ManyToManyField(item, blank=False)
```

Comment: i didn't know anything like this. thanks for the correction. i shall be grateful if you can please explain how dose it works, i am totally new to python and Django framework. if i add `ManyToManyField` in this model, do i also need to change my associate `item` model? sorry i don't know how to tag you here!!

Comment: ManyToManyField allows you to select many items again and again but foreign key allows you to select only one item and you cannot select the item again.

Comment: click tick if I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the choices down to those that the user is associated with:

```
if not usr.choice_set.filter(item_id_id=cid, isactive=1).exists():
```

You also should add a unique_together on `user_id` and `item_id` to prevent duplicates in the database itself as an added layer of protection.

```
class choice(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(user, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now())
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.datetime.now())
    isactive = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('user_id', 'item_id')]
```

Finally, you should really name `choice` as `Choice` and the `user_id` and `item_id` properties as `user` and `item`. As an orm it makes more sense to use `choice_instance.user.username` than `choice_instance.user_id.username`.

Comment: thanks for your reply :) , but my confusion is if i add `unique_together` for both that fields, how other user could use the item which someone else has already chosen? because of unique constraint it wont allow any other person to add item chosen by others.

Comment: upgrade your model.py with unique=True on the field you need to be unique.

Comment: update the code python manage.py makemigrations (specific_app_name) then do python manage.py migrate (specific_app_name) do it can alter the database schema